# Создание веток Git

Tags: git, github

Можно ли на GitHub создать две ветки одного и того же приложения ?
Допустим одна ветка была бы версия на чистом JS, а вторая версия сделана с помощью React. И чтобы после можно было создать GitHub Pages из них.

Comment: Текст вопроса и заголовок как-то крайне слабо связаны между собой

Answer (score 1):

Да, Гитхаб позволяет создавать ветки. Если нужно в этих ветках хранить разные варианты приложения, то можно их создать из одной общей ветки и вести параллельно. На мой взгляд этот подход не имеет никаких преимуществ если эти ветки не будут сливаться.

Также есть такое понятие как `orphan` ветки - ветки без общих родителей. Такой подход используют для того, чтобы хостить github pages сайт. И для случая с github pages это имеет смысл поскольку сайт - часть репозитория. В случае же с двумя проектами это будет только усложнять работу.

- Во-первых ветка "по-умолчанию" всегда одна, так что придётся выбирать какая версия важнее в этом плане.
- Во-вторых - когда нужно работать с не-основной версией проекта (не той, что по умолчанию) придётся всё равно её клон (ну или явно указывать какую именно ветку нужно клонировать).
- В-третьих - если проект будет развиваться активно и параллельно, то ветки разработчиков могут и, скорее всего, будут пересекаться в названиях что внесёт много путаницы - будет непонятно к какой именно версии проекта принадлежит та или иная ветка.
- В-четвёртых, насколько мне известно, можно создать только одну ветку для github pages.

Альтернативой этого подхода будет создание двух разных репозиториев: `<project>-js`, `<project>-react`. Либо же создание организации в гитхаб, которой будут принадлежать эти репозитории.
Есть ещё один вариант - разделить код на ядро и на его "фронт-энд" модули: "JS" и "React" и хранить их в разных папках одного проекта.